# How to apply SSAO to skybox?

Tags: c++, opengl, skybox, ssao

In my limited experience with OpenGL.
I want to apply SSAO to skybox, but the nanosuit(the OBJ object I use) dosn't show ant texture(color). [my wrong example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPmCh.jpg)

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. 
Here are some of my code:
**some in main.cpp**

```
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    float currentTime = glfwGetTime();
    deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;
    lastTime = currentTime;

    DoMovement();

    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.GetZoom()), (float)WIDTH / (float)HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);


    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.GetZoom()), (float)WIDTH / (float)HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        shader.Use();
        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0));
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-90.0f), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.5f));
        shader.setMat4("view", view);
        shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        shader.setMat4("model",model);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemapTexture);
        shader.setVec3("cameraPos", camera.GetPosition());
        ourModel.Draw(shader);

        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        shaderGeometryPass.Use();
        shaderGeometryPass.setMat4("projection", projection);
        shaderGeometryPass.setMat4("view", view);
        // room cube
        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0, 7.0f, 0.0f));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(7.5f, 7.5f, 7.5f));
        shaderGeometryPass.setMat4("model", model);
        shaderGeometryPass.setInt("invertedNormals", 1); // invert normals as we're inside the cube
        renderCube(cubemapTexture);
        shaderGeometryPass.setInt("invertedNormals", 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // 2. generate SSAO texture
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoFBO);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shaderSSAO.Use();
        // Send kernel + rotation
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
            shaderSSAO.setVec3("samples[" + std::to_string(i) + "]", ssaoKernel[i]);
        shaderSSAO.setMat4("projection", projection);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, noiseTexture);
        renderQuad();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


    // 3. blur SSAO texture to remove noise
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoBlurFBO);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shaderSSAOBlur.Use();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssaoColorBuffer);
        renderQuad();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


    // 4. lighting pass: traditional deferred Blinn-Phong lighting with added screen-space ambient occlusion
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    shaderLightingPass.Use();
    // send light relevant uniforms
    glm::vec3 lightPosView = glm::vec3(camera.GetViewMatrix() * glm::vec4(lightPos, 1.0));
    shaderLightingPass.setVec3("light.Position", lightPosView);
    shaderLightingPass.setVec3("light.Color", lightColor);
    // Update attenuation parameters
    const float linear    = 0.09;
    const float quadratic = 0.0032;
    shaderLightingPass.setFloat("light.Linear", linear);
    shaderLightingPass.setFloat("light.Quadratic", quadratic);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedoSpec);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3); // add extra SSAO texture to lighting pass
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssaoColorBufferBlur);
    renderQuad();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
unsigned int quadVAO = 0;
unsigned int quadVBO;
void renderQuad()
{
    if (quadVAO == 0)
    {
        float quadVertices[] = {
                // positions        // texture Coords
                -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        };
        // setup plane VAO
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &quadVBO);
        glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices), &quadVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    }
    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
unsigned int cubeVAO = 0;
unsigned int cubeVBO = 0;
void renderCube(unsigned int spheremapTexture)
{
    // initialize (if necessary)
    if (cubeVAO == 0)
    {
        float vertices[] = {
                // back face
                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
                1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
                1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
                1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
                -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
                // front face
                -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
                1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
                1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
                1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
                -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
                -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
                // left face
                -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-right
                -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom-left
                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom-left
                -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
                -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-right
                // right face
                1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-left
                1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom-right
                1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
                1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom-right
                1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-left
                1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
                // bottom face
                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
                1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
                1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
                1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
                -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
                // top face
                -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
                1.0f,  1.0f , 1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
                1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
                1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
                -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
                -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f  // bottom-left
        };
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
        // fill buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        // link vertex attributes
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
    // render Cube
    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, spheremapTexture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
}
```

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: the skybox on the model works fine when without SSAO

Comment: A skybox represents everything that is considered infinitely far away from the scene. How would it make sense to put ambient occlusion on such a thing? Skyboxes also tend to represent a *sky*, which doesn't cause occlusion. Lastly, the skybox geometry doesn't represent the geometry of the actual sky being represented, so using its geometry to cause occlusion is wrong-headed.